# Code Vita: Chakravyuha

Tags: performance, algorithm, c, programming-challenge

**Problem Statement**

> A Chakravyuha is a wheel-like formation. Pictorially it is depicted as
>   below
>
> [image]
>
> A Chakravyuha has a very well-defined co-ordinate system. Each point
>   on the co-ordinate system is manned by a certain unit of the army. The
>   Commander-In-Chief is always located at the center of the army to
>   better co-ordinate his forces. The only way to crack the Chakravyuha
>   is to defeat the units in sequential order.
>
> A Sequential order of units differs structurally based on the radius
>   of the Chakra. The radius can be thought of as length or breadth of
>   the matrix depicted above. The structure i.e. placement of units in
>   sequential order is as shown below
>
> [image]
>
> The entry point of the Chakravyuha is always at the (0,0) co-ordinate
>   of the matrix above. This is where the 1st army unit guards. From
>   (0,0) i.e. 1st unit Abhimanyu has to march towards the center at (2,2)
>   where the 25th i.e. the last of the enemy army unit guards. Remember
>   that he has to proceed by destroying the units in sequential fashion.
>   After destroying the first unit, Abhimanyu gets a power point.
>   Thereafter, he gets one after destroying army units which are
>   multiples of 11. You should also be a in a position to tell Yudhisthir
>   Maharaj the location at which Abhimanyu collected his power points.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> First line of input will be length as well as breadth of the army units, say N
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> - Print NxN matrix depicting the placement of army units, with unit numbers delimited by (\t) Tab character
> - Print Total power points collected
> - Print coordinates of power points collected in sequential fashion (one per line)
> - Print coordinates of power points collected in sequential fashion (one per line)
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> 0 < N <=100
>
> **The Logic:**
>
> [image]

```
#include<stdio.h>

int isDiv(int);

int main(){

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    //check contraint
    if(n<=0 || n>100){
        return 0;
    }

    int a[100][100]; // main matrix

    int counter=1; // keeps track of number

    int i,j; //keeps track of position

    int w;   // w - window 

    int size=n-1; // size - size of segment of window

    for( w = 0 ; w < n / 2 ; w++){
        i = w;
        j = w;

        //go right
        for( j = j ; j < size + w ; j++){
            a[ i ][ j ] = counter;
            counter++;
        }

        //go down
        for( i = i ; i < size + w ; i++){
            a[ i ][ j ] = counter;
            counter++;
        }

        //go left
        for( j = j ; j > w ; j--){
            a[ i ][ j ] = counter;
            counter++;
        }

        //go up
        for( i = i ; i > w ; i--){
            a[ i ][ j ] = counter;
            counter++;
        }
        size = size-2;
    }
    if( n % 2 != 0){
        a[ w ][ w ] = counter;      
    }

    //print matrix
    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        for( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
            printf("%d\t", a[ i ][ j ]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int no_div = (n*n)/11 + 1 ; // no of divisibles

    printf("Total Power points : %d\n",no_div);

    printf("(0,0)\n");

    size=n-1;

    //print positions
    for( w = 0 ; w < n / 2 ; w++){
        i = w;
        j = w;

        //go right
        for( j = j ; j < size + w ; j++){
            if(isDiv( a[ i ][ j ] )){
                printf("(%d,%d)\n", i, j);
            }
        }

        //go down
        for( i = i ; i < size + w ; i++){
            if(isDiv( a[ i ][ j ] )){
                printf("(%d,%d)\n", i, j);
            }
        }

        //go left
        for( j = j ; j > w ; j--){
            if(isDiv( a[ i ][ j ] )){
                printf("(%d,%d)\n", i, j);
            }
        }

        //go up
        for( i = i ; i > w ; i--){
            if(isDiv( a[ i ][ j ] )){
                printf("(%d,%d)\n", i, j);
            }
        }
        size = size-2;
    }
    if( n % 2 != 0){
        if(isDiv( a[ i ][ j ] )){
            printf("(%d,%d)\n", i, j);
        }       
    }

    return 0;
}

int isDiv(int x){
    if( x % 11 == 0 ){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The code is working fine as can be checked on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/4jX2sc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to keep your `main` function small and focused. (Well, you should try to keep *every* function you write small and focused!) For example, you might do something like this:

```
struct Coord {
    int row, col;
};
struct CoordList {
    int size;
    Coord *data;
};

void print_coords(Coord c, FILE *out) {
    printf("(%d,%d)\n", c.row, c.col);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    print_tab_delimited_matrix(n, stdout);
    CoordList coords = collect_power_points(n);
    printf("%d\n", coords.size);
    for (int i=0; i < coords.size; ++i) {
        print_coords(coords.data[i]);
    }
}
```

Writing the little functions `print_tab_delimited_matrix` and `collect_power_points` is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

Or, you might consider that there's no real point to collecting up all of the power-point coordinates in a *physical* list. You already know the *formula* for computing where each power point is picked up! So you might scrap the above code and rewrite your whole program as:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    print_tab_delimited_matrix(n, stdout);
    int n2 = n * n;
    printf("%d\n", 1 + (n2 / 11));
    print_coords(get_coords_of_army(1, n), stdout);
    for (int i = 11; i <= n2; i += 11) {
        print_coords(get_coords_of_army(i, n), stdout);
    }
}
```

Writing the function `get_coords_of_army` is left as an exercise for the reader. But the important thing to realize is that *writing that function is supposed to be the challenge!* You should develop the instinct and intuition for quickly breaking down a problem statement into sub-problems, and then solving those sub-problems. Notice that outside of `main` I don't need to do any input or output; I just have a very clean mathematical problem to solve.

```
Coord get_coords_of_army(int which_army, int breadth_of_square);
```

Everything else going on in this problem statement is basically a red herring.

---

I note in passing that `isDiv(x)` is *not* a good name for a function that computes whether `x` is divisible by 11. You get points for naming it `is...`-something, but surely (A) `is_divisible_by_11` would have been a better name, and (B) you don't really need a *function* for that!

You could make the argument that this is futureproofing the code: what if the next iteration of the puzzle changes the locations of the power points? That's fair, and makes `is_divisible_by_11` a bad name... but it doesn't make `isDiv` a *good* name! We might better write

```
bool has_power_point(int which_army) {
    return (which_army == 1) || (which_army % 11 == 0);
}
```

and then back in our main function we can write simply

```
    printf("%d\n", 1 + (n2 / 11));
    for (int i = 1; i <= n2; ++i) {
        if (has_power_point(i)) {
            print_coords(get_coords_of_army(i, n), stdout);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So my logic to create the matrix is good ? . I didnt find anything about it in the review. Thanks.

Comment: @Phoenix: Well, I didn't look at your code very deeply — just deeply enough to see that it was one huge clump of nested for-loops that I didn't want to get too far into. From the above review, you should be able to tell that I would have tried to write `print_tab_delimited_matrix(n)` in terms of `get_army_for_coords(coords, n)`, which is just the inverse of `get_coords_of_army(i, n)`. (Think about how to use that relationship to write *unit tests* for your code!)